# sql boolean 0/1 To Represent true or False

Tags: sql

In my database 1 is used to represent true and 0 to represent false. In my column, now i was wondering if anyone can help me write a query that outputs if the value equals to 1 display true if equals to 0 display false?.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Please clear your question and give bit detail about the which database you are using

Comment: The more common approach for this is to not do this in the query itself, but in the application.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try to use `case`

```
select case when col = 1 then 'true'
            when col = 0 then 'false'
       else 'NN'
       end as val
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select case when your_bool_column = 1 
            then 'true'
            else 'false'
       end as bool_col
from your_table
```